# Misunderstanding of Objects in an Array

Tags: javascript

To translate my Objects into an Array, I'm using this function :

```js
$scope.valuesToArray = function(obj) 
{
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
}
```

But I don't understand why I have this form "Array[2]" in my Array instead of "Array[0]" :

[image]

Actually, I don't really care the form of this Array, but it appears that this way doesn't allow me to use, for exemple :

```js
 $scope.createdEvent = $scope.valuesToArray($scope.createdEvent);
 
console.log("What I have :", $scope.createdEvent);

console.log("I want to print this : ", $scope.createdEvent.creatorName);
 
 // CONSOLE.LOG GOT UNDEFINED
```

**EDIT** :

To be more specific, I would like to understand the difference between the two Array you can see on the picture. Because they are and they contain exactly the same objects and informations. But with the one which shows "Array[2]", when I'm trying to copy it in an other Array, like so :

```js
 $scope.newCrea = [];
 $scope.newCrea = $scope.createdEvent;
 console.log("TEST", $scope.newCrea); // GOT UNDEFINED
```

Or when I'm trying to use his attributes's objects in my HTML view, like {{newCrea.creatorName}}, I got nothing.

$scope.createdEvent contains two objects, with foreach two attributes : "creatorName" and "dateEvent".

Comment: Why do you want it to return an empty array?

Comment: `Array[0]` is actually an empty array. subscript `0` tells you the length of the array.

Comment: `Array[2]` is because you have an array *with 2 members*. That's how it's supposed to look in the console. I'm not sure what you are asking here

Comment: You want an Array to act like an Object, than why are you converting it to an Array?

Comment: Don't post images, post text. Code snippets should run, not throw errors. Your issue seems to be more about confusion over what the console is displaying.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what the input object looks like.

Comment: `Array[2]` in the image you posted means the inspected object is an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that contains 2 elements. The `0` and `1` on the subsequent lines are the indices where the values are stored in the array. As the image shows, they are [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)s. What you probably want to access is `$scope.createdEvent[0].creatorName`.

Comment: So I understand the difference between Array[0] and Array[2], but I still don't understand why I got an undefined error, trying to manipulate this Array[2]. I have edited my question to try to be more specific. Thank you @axiac $scope.createdEvent[0].creatorName, worked to read it in the console.

Comment: `$scope` is an array, it doesn't have the property you want to access (`.createdEvent`). You initialize `$scope.newCrea` with something that doesn't exist (`$scope.createEvent`). In Javascript, a property that doesn't exist is `undefined`.

Comment: Oh I see, so now I'm completely lost ! xD How am I supposed to declare my Array ? I thought that $scope variables was like "globale variables", aren't they ?

Answer (score 1):

It's normal with your code, it keeps index

For "Array-like Objects" use :

```
var myObj = {
    1: ['c', 'd'],
    2: ['a', 'b']
 };
 var myArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(myObj, 0);
```

You can have a look here http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/

Comment: I tried this, but I've got an empty Array. Thank you for the link by the way !

Comment: Like you said you got "undefined" with $scope.createdEvent.Maybe a problem in this way.